# calc() is crashing IE 9 when set on background-position

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm using [calc()](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) to position an image 10px from the right of a responsive container. I have a declaration like so:

```
background-position: calc(100% - 10px) 6px;
```

Whenever I try to:

- load that CSS into the page normally or
- enter it via Developer Tools

IE 9 completely crashes. No errors in Developer Tools, just straight to crash. This works in all other (future) browsers but my goal is to support IE 9 as well.

`calc()` seems to work on other properties like `margin` and `width` just fine. Here is the full CSS trace of the related element:

[image]

Here it's set to `98%`, but when I use `calc` on `background-position-x` (as shown above) IE 9 crashes.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but try `background-position: calc(100% - 10px) calc(6px + 0);`.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to `calc()`, you could use the `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` keywords to specify different edges (rather than the default top-left) from which to offset your background content.

```
background-position: right 10px top 6px; /* 10px from the right, 6px from the top */
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

> If two values are given … the first represents the horizontal position … the second represents the vertical. … *Values represent an offset of the top-left corner of the background image from the top-left corner of the background positioning area.*
>
> If four values are given, then each represents an offset and must be preceded by a *keyword that specifies from which edge the offset is given*.

If you prefer `calc()` but want to prevent older browsers from crashing, you could define a fallback value (`calc()` is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) for `background-position` in IE9-).

```
background-position-x: 98%;
background-position-y: 6px;
background-position: calc(100% - 10px) 6px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a shot in the dark here. But maybe try:

```
background-position: expression(100% - 10px) 6px;
```

FYI: I am not very experienced with expression(). I have however used it in the past to accomplish a similar goal on a mobile browser. Maybe it will work for you in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article [Positioning background from element’s bottom-right corner](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/09/css3-background-position/)

So a solution for your problem will be something like this:

```
background-position: 6px right 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using calc or an expression, what worked for me is using absolutely positioned elements and stretching the images using the left and right properties.

```
.bg_img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-10px;
  right:-10px;
}
```

The negative pixels aren't necessary in most cases, but for me that's what I was trying to achieve with the calc().

Hope this helps someone!